# How to draw text through line and How to highlight the text on mouse enter using Html Canvas. Please help me

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can draw a line as per direction but I am not being able to draw a text as per line direction. My paint will be like this...

[image: arrow line with text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to figure out how wide the text will be and that can be solved with:

```
ctx.measureText(text).width;
```

Then just create a funtion that draws lines on either side of it (and a arrow head). Finish everything off with rotating the whole canvas before drawing it, like so:

Original answer: http://jsfiddle.net/txrvLLjp

**EDIT**
New code allows for adding starting and stopping points instead.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var text = "Knows";
var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180;
ctx.font = "12px Arial";

drawArrow(text,40,40,200,200);

function drawArrow(text,startX,startY,stopX,stopY) {
    var deltaX = (stopX-startX);
    var deltaY = (stopY-startY)
    
    //calculating the total length of the line
    var arrowLength=Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY);
    //calculating the angle
    var angle=Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(startX,startY);
    ctx.rotate(angle*TO_RADIANS);
    var textLength = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    var padding=(arrowLength-textLength)/2;
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(padding,0);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillText(text,padding,4);
    ctx.moveTo(padding+textLength,0);
    ctx.lineTo(padding+textLength+padding,0);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    //Arrow point below
    ctx.moveTo(padding+textLength+padding,0);
    ctx.lineTo(padding+textLength+padding-8,8);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.moveTo(padding+textLength+padding,0);
    ctx.lineTo(padding+textLength+padding-8,-8);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Actually the line direction may change(movable line) so angle would be calculated as per direction. I want to know is there any jquery function or library to write text over a line. I will provide starting and ending vertex(Coordinate position) and text , it draw the both as per my requirement. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I've changed the code slightly to allow entering the text, a starting point and a stopping point. The function handles the rest. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any jquery function that does that so I tried making my own ;)

Comment: Its ok.........you have done coordinate problem...please try with drawArrow(text,40,40,200,40); It should draw horizontally but its doing vertically

Comment: Sorry about that, it's been corrected now. I had mixed up the x- and y-coordinates in `Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX)`. I updated the answer above but here's a working fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/txrvLLjp/2/